# Как разыменовать Box в rust-gdb?

Tags: rust, gdb

Пытаясь отладить свой код, написанный на Rust, я задался вопросом:

Как узнать на данные какого типа указывает `Box<dyn ...>` и как печатать эти данные (поля структуры)?

Печатаю переменную s:

```
(gdb) p s
$1 = core::option::Option<alloc::boxed::Box<StmtAble, alloc::alloc::Global>>::Some(izber::ir::Box<StmtAble, alloc::alloc::Global> {pointer: 0x5555555d9b70, vtable: 0x5555555d1950})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`s.0`, что бы достать внутренности из Option, и `*` для разыменования Box'а:

```
(gdb) l
1       #![allow(unused_variables, dead_code)]
2       trait T {}
3       struct S { a: u32, b: String }
4       impl T for S {}
5       fn main() {
6           let a: Box<dyn T> = Box::new(S { a: 7, b: "abc".into()});
7           let b: Option<Box<dyn T>> = Some(Box::new(S { a: 8, b: "def".into()}));
8           println!("test");
9       }
10
(gdb) b main.rs:8
Breakpoint 1 at 0x156cd: file src/main.rs, line 8.
(gdb) r
<...>
Breakpoint 1, dbgtest::main () at src/main.rs:8
8           println!("test");
(gdb) p *a
$1 = dbgtest::S {a: 7, b: "abc"}
(gdb) p *(b.0)
$2 = dbgtest::S {a: 8, b: "def"}
```

Comment: А теперь попробуйте 8 строку заменить на `let a = Some(Box::new(S { a: 7, b: "abc".into()}));`. В моём примере s - это Option<Box<...>>

Comment: Тогда `p *(a.0)`.

Comment: Что в GDB означает .0 ?

Comment: Это просто доступ к полю кортежа - https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/tuple-expr.html#tuple-indexing-expressions - т.е. к содержимому Option::Some в нашем случае.

Comment: Option - это кортеж ?

Comment: Option это перечисление из двух вариантов, один из которых (Some) является кортежной структурой (tuple struct) с одним безымянным полем.